# How to use TestNG listener with Extent reports 4

Tags: java, selenium, testing, extentreports

I'm trying to figure out how to use the listeners in order to add them to my testso after each test the reports will be generated automaticly,
my structure looks like these:
[image: structure]
and where it's red there i want to add the listeners,

my extentmanager class looks like these:

```java
public class ExtentManager {
    public  ExtentReports extent;
    public  ExtentTest test;
    public  ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public  String reportDate;
    public  String filePath;

    public  void init() {
        reportDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date());    
        filePath = ".\\reports\\OrangeHRM Report "+ reportDate;
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(filePath+"/report.html");
        new File(filePath).mkdirs();

        extent = new ExtentReports();                    
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);            

        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("automation report on OrangeHRM");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("OrangeHRM Test");               
        htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("windows-1255");                      
    }

    public void create_test(String testName, String testDescription)
    {
        test = extent.createTest (testName, testDescription);
    }

    public String CaptureScreen() throws AWTException, IOException
    {
        String picDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date());
        String imagePath = filePath+"/pic"+picDate+".jpg";
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(screenShot, "jpg", new File(imagePath));
        return imagePath;
    }
}
```

and after it at BaseTest class i called the method init(); to start the extentReports, than MainRunner extends BaseTest and there each tese is marked with test.pass or test.fail - using IF.
i want to avoid it and to use the listeners so eacg test is working with assert so it can be mark the result at the listener and than to the report, so how to do it?

also, what is the difference in the listeners?